# How to not force a type and return the same result?

Tags: typescript, types, nestjs

I am using the below code to return memory usage in megabytes (instead of bytes):

```
const memoryUsage = process.memoryUsage();
const result = Object.entries(memoryUsage).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
acc[key] = value / 1024 / 1024;
return acc;
}, {} as Record<string, number>);
return result;
```

The result I am getting is this:

```
{
  "rss": 82.1875,
  "heapTotal": 54.60546875,
  "heapUsed": 24.929443359375,
  "external": 20.77628231048584,
  "arrayBuffers": 17.465116500854492
}
```

which I thought was well done but now I am being asked to do the same thing **without forcing types** and I have no idea how to do it...any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Are they concerned by that `as Record<string, number>`? Typescript wouldn't know the type of `{}` without that. The other option would be is make a `const initial: Record<string, number> = {}`before the `reduce` call and pass it that way.

Comment: I think they expect me to ditch the whole reduce call and just do it differently from scratch without forcing types...